# CFBundleDisplayName in the Top Shelf's Info.plist

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, info-plist

Usually, in the Top Shelf target the value for `CFBundleDisplayName` is `TopShelf` (for example, in [PopcornTimeTV](https://github.com/PopcornTimeTV/PopcornTimeTV/blob/master/TopShelf/Info.plist)). What value should I use for `CFBundleDisplayName`? Where can I see this value in the Top Shelf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CFBundleDisplayName` for a top-shelf extension is not visible to the user on the Apple TV device.

You can use any value you like. I use `TopShelfExtension`. But as you suggested in your post: `TopShelf` would also work just fine.